# How to start scalala console?

Tags: scala, scalala

I am starting using `scala` and I am interested in using the `scalala` package for doing linear algebra computations. I successfully installed it through `sbt` but I can't (or better don't know how) start the `scalala console`. Can anyone point out the steps I have to take to make that possible?

Thanks a lot

P.S. I have read [this quickstart guide](https://github.com/scalala/Scalala/wiki/QuickStart) but didn't help me.

[EDIT]

To be more clear I do not want to explicitly make includes with the standard `scala` console in order `scalala` to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### UPDATE:

If you want start Scalala console without explicitly import those package, then maybe you need build a excutable jar directly from the GitHub repo.

The following steps should work:

1. `git clone https://github.com/scalala/Scalala`
2. `cd Scalala`
3. `./sbt update compile proguard`
4. `java -jar target/scala_2.8.1/scalala_2.8.1-1.0.0.RC2-SNAPSHOT.min.jar`

And now you should get an Scala console with Scalala package imported by default.

---

Since the document says the scalala console just a standard Scala console with default package imported.

You could just run `sbt` under your project directory, and using `console` command to enter Scala console mode.

Finally, type in the following code:

```
import scalala.scalar._;
import scalala.tensor.::;
import scalala.tensor.mutable._;
import scalala.tensor.dense._;
import scalala.tensor.sparse._;
import scalala.library.Library._;
import scalala.library.LinearAlgebra._;
import scalala.library.Statistics._;
import scalala.library.Plotting._;
import scalala.operators.Implicits._;
```

Now you should be able to use Scalala just like the document sayas.

Answer (score 0):

run

```
java -jar target/scala_2.8.1/scalala*.min.jar
```

or the equivalent for your release of scalala.  Optionally, you could run the standard scala console and type in the following includes

```
import scalala.scalar._;
import scalala.tensor._;
import scalala.tensor.mutable._;
import scalala.tensor.dense._;
import scalala.tensor.sparse._;
import scalala.library.Library._;
import scalala.library.LinearAlgebra._;
import scalala.library.Statistics._;
import scalala.library.Plotting._;
import scalala.operators.Implicits._;
```

Was there something beyond the instructions you were having an issue with?  Citing specific errors or specific problems encountered is a great way to get a more specific answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Edwin. I do not have any jar file in there and I suspect that the `proguard` command will have to generate it as the quickstart guide suggests. But when I am trying to type `proguard` I get errors that the command does not exist. Any pointers there? (If I sound a newbie it's because I am :)) What's that `proguard` anyway?

Comment: @Gerry, sorry, I don't have much experience with `proguard`, I only know a bit of scala.